# Any converter to put a css stylesheet into style tags in html?

Tags: html, css, styles

*Edit: Title should refer to style **attributes**. My bad.*

I created a little project (html + css) in order to create a signature for emails. However, I just realized I need just html, no css. Is there any tool that can do from:

```
.signature_box{
    display: flex;
    position: relative;
}
```

to:

```
<div style="display:flex; position: relative;">...</div>
```

by detecting that the div has '`class="signature_box"`'?

Comment: paste your html + the css in here: https://templates.mailchimp.com/resources/inline-css/

Answer (score 0):

Use this tool to paste your entire HTML and it will convert the `<styles>` into  where it is needed, like magic. Very good for e-mail templates.

https://templates.mailchimp.com/resources/inline-css/